# Toggle implementation for custom RadioButton

Tags: radio-button, javafx-2

I need to create a custom `RadioButton` without circle. Its a very simple class that extends `Label` and implements `Toggle`.
I added a mouse clicked handler :

```
private class MouseClickedHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            final Toggle toggle = (Toggle) t.getSource();
            if (!toggle.isSelected()) {
                getToggleGroup().selectToggle(toggle);
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem is to set a default selected radio button.
If on one of the `RadioButton` I call `setSelected(true)` after its creation and after adding it to a `ToggleGroup`, when I launch the application if I click on other radio buttons in the group, the `ToggleGroup` does its job of deselecting except for that default one.  I always end up with 2 radio buttons selected, the one on which I called setSelected(true) directly, and the one currently selected by a click.

I corrected it - Complete code :

```
public class RadioBtn extends Label implements Toggle {

    private ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroup = null;
    private BooleanProperty selectedProperty = null;

    public RadioBtn {
      initHandlers();
    }

    @Override
    public ToggleGroup getToggleGroup() {
        return toggleGroupProperty().get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setToggleGroup(ToggleGroup tg) {
        if (getToggleGroup() == null) {
            toggleGroupProperty().set(tg);
        }
        getToggleGroup().getToggles().add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectProperty<ToggleGroup> toggleGroupProperty() {
        if (toggleGroup == null) {
            toggleGroup = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        }
        return toggleGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selectedProperty().get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelected(boolean bln) {
        selectedProperty().set(bln);
    }

    @Override
    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        if (selectedProperty == null) {
            selectedProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        }
        return selectedProperty;
    }


    protected void initHandlers() {
        if (getToggleGroup() != null) {
            setOnMouseClicked(new ToggleGroupHandler());
        }
    }

    private class ToggleGroupHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            final Toggle toggle = (Toggle) t.getSource();
            if (!toggle.isSelected()) {
                /*if(getToggleGroup().getSelectedToggle() != null) {
                    getToggleGroup().getSelectedToggle().setSelected(false);
                }*/
                getToggleGroup().selectToggle(toggle);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `radioButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);`? This eliminates implementing MouseClickedHandler. Otherwise provide more details, and explain your problem more clearly. Especially "ToggleGroup does its job of deselecting except for that default one.".

Comment: The problem closely related with your custom radioButton. You need to provide it as well. However, if your final aim is to customize the radiobutton visually only, you can achieve it by CSS and/or custom RadioButtonSkin.